# Java. Efficient check for winning condition in 5 in raw

Tags: java, performance, bots

I've started writing a bot to play Gomoku. Briefly each player tries to score unbroken line of five tolkens. The game is played on 15*15 board.

Finding a win in one move by exhaust search is the first task.

Should I use 1D or 2D array to represent the board? 2D seems more natural, but 1D array might be faster.

What is the resource efficient way to check the winning condition?

I considered making an array.

win[i][j]=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5], where win[i] is (the set of winning combos ) && (with one tolken in i-th position).

What would be an efficient way to do this check?

Also, how can I account for all winning combos by forking moves? The total number of winning combos will be quite large? Should I move to on the fly evaluation.

Thank you in advance,
Stepan

Comment: You should use 2D array. And I don't think you should think a lot about resources if you use 15*15 array. It's better to write simple and human-readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use 1D or 2D array?

I think that you could either 1 or 2 dimension array, and with each (i, j) you could access to your cell. in 1D you must code to find correct index of the array and in 2D, simply you could access to your cells. 
so in this sample code I use a 2D array.

> What is the resource efficient way to check the winning condition?

you have to check the cell values with fix values (eg. booleans or numbers) frequently and the lowest assembly structure of equal statement is checking zero flag. so I think that the most efficient isEqual is for Boolean.

so in this sample code I use Boolean.

since Gomoku has 2 players, each cell could have 3 values (black, wight, empty), but we could use 2 arrays of Boolean for each player and each cell has 2 values (stone, empty) for that player.

```
public class Main {

    final static int row = 15;
    final static int column = 15;
    final static int win_count = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[][] board1 = new boolean[row][column];
        boolean[][] board2 = new boolean[row][column];
        /*
         * for each change by player1 in (i,j) in the board. (index start from 0
         * to 14)
         */
        int i = 2;
        int j = 3;
        Boolean win = checkWin(board1, i, j);
        System.out.println("player1 win=" + win);
    }

    private static Boolean checkWin(boolean[][] board1, int i, int j) {
        /**
         * 1) check horizontal
         */
        int leftBound = 0;
        if (j - win_count >= 0)
            leftBound = j - win_count;
        else
            leftBound = 0;

        int rightBound = 0;
        if (j + win_count < column)
            rightBound = j + win_count;
        else
            rightBound = column - 1;

        int hitCount = 0;
        int jk = j;

        // go left
        while (jk >= leftBound && hitCount < win_count) {
            if (board1[i][jk]) {
                hitCount++;
                jk--;
            } else {
                jk = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        // go right

        while (jk <= rightBound && hitCount < win_count) {
            if (board1[i][jk]) {
                hitCount++;
                jk++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (hitCount >= win_count)
            return true;

        /**
         * 2) check vertical
         */

        /**
         * 3) check principal diagonal 
         */

        /**
         * 4) check minor diagonal
         */

        // otherwise:

        return false;
    }

}
```

I write the structure of this code and you should complete other parts that is marked with comments.

I hope this sample code could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article for ideas:
"Go-Moku Solved by New Search Techniques" (1993)

Briefly,

(1) A brute force 2 ply deep search is a cheap and dirty approach, but there is a better way
(2) Whenever forcing moves are involved you can run 10-20 ply deep search in a second
(3) Human professionals rely on this; your bot should utilize it as well

Hope this helps.